# Put Query String Before Hash in Angular 7 Routing

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a larger application that contains an Angular page within it. The outside application uses the query string to store some of its state (not my decision). The Angular page uses routing.

I've tried a couple of approaches, using PathLocationStrategy and supplying my own provider for APP_BASE_HREF, but wind up with urls that look like this:

/my-page/#/?foo=bar/my-route

when I'm looking to get to:

/my-page?foo=bar#/my-route

Is there a way to accomplish this? Note that I only know that foo=bar at runtime. Subsequent visits to the page may yield:

/my-page?foo=baz#/my-route
or
/my-page?foo=qux#/my-route
or
/my-page?foo=12345#/my-route

I've tried, in app.module.ts:

```js
    export function getBaseLocation(): string {
      return location.toString()
        .replace(`${location.protocol}//`, '')
        .replace(location.host, '');
    }
    @NgModule({
    // ...
      providers: [{
        provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
        useFactory: getBaseLocation,
      },
    //...
    });
```

and in app.component.ts:

```js
  constructor(
    private pathLocationStrategy: PathLocationStrategy,
    private router: Router) {
    if (this.pathLocationStrategy.getBaseHref() !== this.pathLocationStrategy.path()) {
      this.router.navigateByUrl(this.pathLocationStrategy.path());
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you succeeded in getting the querystring parameters before the #, you'd essentially be reloading your entire Angular app with each route change. Why do you need it there? If you just want it included for calls to your API, I'd try using an HttpInterceptor and rewrite the url there instead.

Comment: @adam0101 My expectation would be that the Angular app would respond to hash changes while preserving the url and query string (which it doesn't use at all). The bad behavior is that if the user attempts a page refresh, we lose the query string and, thus, the state kept in the query string.

Comment: How are you losing the query string? Is your server not configured to serve up the index.html from any route and so redirecting to your homepage? If so, that's the problem you should be addressing.

Comment: @adam0101: the query string gets lost on initial routing, as Angular takes it over. The broader application, of which this Angular piece is just a small part, does its routing through the query string, and changing that isn't currently an option for me.